# Move zoomed image inside picturebox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the same code posted in [render-multiple-image-layers-to-transparent-png-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871361/render-multiple-image-layers-to-transparent-png-image).
I add zoom function, I want an Image to move inside the PictureBox. It shouldn't be possible that you can drag it out  leaving me white areas.

I need to use that code because Im using 2 images layered.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you painting the Bitmap(s) or the Image is assigned to the `PictureBox.Image` property? Or both? Or one is the BackGroundImage and one is painted or assigned? How are you planning to move this/these image(s)? By dragging it/them? With a slider? Where's the layered Image?

Comment: Btw, simple class to manage layered transparent images of variable size: [Make a png image transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083671/7444103).

Comment: Yes, I dragging back picture, the original code let you drag image, images are assingned to .Image property of each layer:
`code`
 Dim l As Layer
 l = New Layer("Layer 1")
l.ImageItems.Add(New ImageItem(Image.FromFile(FilePath)